# How to avoid "%3D1" from getting removed in the response node?

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity, integration-procedure

I am currently using an Integration procedure to generate a url.
In a loop block, I'm using a Set Value, to pass a url String to response block which is outside the loop. (Using Response JSON Path & Response JSON Node in the Set value)
When I fetch the url value in the response block json node, it removes the substring '%3D1' from the url value . ( Using additional Output Response key value pair in Response action block)

Comment: the actual substring that gets removed is %3D1%